# Additional shorter URL for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, url-shortener

In the same way a YouTube video of URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqcf2GGiczU has a permanent shorter URL (for easier sharing) `youtu.be/Vqcf2GGiczU`, is there a similar thing for posts?

Example for comments in code:

```
print("foo bar")  # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185, but we also have to do foo and bar
# too long!
print("foo bar")  # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185, but we also have to do foo and bar
# better
print("foo bar")  # see s.tk/q419185, but we also have to do foo and bar
# would be even better for comments readability!
```

TL;DR: Could there be an additional shorter URL, for every post?

For future reference, this post is linked with the (upvoted, but declined) [Please add question and answer shortlinks with site names to the s.tk URL shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110407/please-add-question-and-answer-shortlinks-with-site-names-to-the-s-tk-url-shorte).

I learned that the `s.tk` domain belongs to Stack Overflow, it could be a great opportunity!

Comment: Nope, no such service exists (within SE's scope, at least)

Comment: @ThomA Can you please elaborate? What would be the drawback of having an additional URL, minified?

Comment: A waste of developer time when they should be fixing *actual* problems, for a start. `//stackoverflow.com/a/419185` is short enough.

Comment: Shorter isn't necessarily more readable... I, personally, prefer seeing unminified urls.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe minified isn't the right term. I mean in the same way than `youtu.be/Vqcf2GGiczU` instead of `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqcf2GGiczU`: the same `id` appears. Maybe "shorter" is the right term and not "minified".

Comment: Doesn't really matter how you call it, tbh :D

Comment: For the record, `youtu.be/Vqcf2GGiczU` isn't a URL. If you are fine to write `sta.ck/419185` you may as well write `stackoverflow.com/a/419185`.

Comment: Exactly how is the short youtube link "easier sharing" ? You copy-paste a url, or through a phone app you choose to "share" it. The url itself is entirely detached from that process. Unless you've been manually typing them in, in which case I would really advise you to stop doing that.

Comment: Declined in the past: [Please add question and answer shortlinks with site names to the s.tk URL shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110407/241919) (2011).

Comment: Why should Stack Overflow register a domain with Cook Islands?  What does that have to do with Stack Overflow?

Comment: @AnonCoward You know it was just a simple example in my post, no need to ironize on this particular domain :-)

Comment: Meta never fails to amaze me with how harsh suggestions are turned down using the "I personally don't like it" excuse lol. I'll do the same then... I personally would appreciate shortened URL's, since I have problems reading over long URL's, espescially since I have a zoom in my browser and there's already less space available on the window.

Comment: "For future reference, this post is linked with the (well-received)..." I don't understand how this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Because you cannot dupe vote to MSE, @KarlKnechtel

Comment: If you click on the "share" button I believe it gives you a shorter url than what is shown on the address bar

Comment: @cuzy well at least that's a valid argument for shorter URLs. The first one made in this post. Requesting change just for the sake of change is never going to have any chance of success.

Answer (score 17):

There is no URL shortener that is focused only on Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange) posts. The shortest URL you can have is in the form

- `https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185` for answers<sup>1</sup>
- `https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163` for questions<sup>1</sup>

Which can further be shortened by removing the protocol: `//stackoverflow.com/a/419185` and `//stackoverflow.com/q/419163`. This is going to use protocol relative URL, thus using HTTP or HTTPS depending on the current domain where the link is.

Yet it saves a total of 5 characters.

---

<sup>1</sup> actually the `a` or `q` in the URL does not matter. The ID of the post will lead to the correct place, `https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185` and `https://stackoverflow.com/q/419185` work the same, as well as `https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163` and `https://stackoverflow.com/a/419163`

Answer (score 16):

There is no advantage on having shorter URLs for "sharing", unless we are aiming for sharing in social sites, where character count may be a limitation. A use case for which I personally derive zero value.

For most purposes, it's useful that the URL exhibits some indication of what will be found on the other side of the link. Having a shorter version that makes it easier to hide that information, and no value (I would argue that it actually subtracts value).

I disagree something like that should be created. The existing options, such as they are, are more than enough. No need to build something worse.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need links in comments in the code blocks, provide the links in a numbered list after the code block, or on the bottom of your answer, and refer to this list in the comments, for instance `// See link 3`. That will prevent littering the code block, *and* you don’t have to open the links to get any sort of idea what they’re about, because you’ll read the Q/A’s title in the list, without leaving the page with your answer.